# CRITICAL Uncaught Error: Call to a member function register_controller() on null in elementor-pro/core/app/modules/site-editor/module.php:80

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, elementor

Can someone assist in solving this mystery?

I have a client who is using Elementor Pro and Woocommerce.  Up until the most recent woocommerce updates, the site was running fine.  Now we are unable to take credit card payments and this error is populating in the log.

```
2020-09-15T11:25:43+00:00 CRITICAL Uncaught Error: Call to a member function register_controller() on null in /.../wp-content/plugins/elementor-pro/core/app/modules/site-editor/module.php:80
Stack trace:
#0 /.../wp-content/plugins/elementor-pro/core/app/app.php(76): ElementorPro\Core\App\Modules\SiteEditor\Module->__construct()
#1 /.../wp-content/plugins/elementor-pro/plugin.php(324): ElementorPro\Core\App\App->__construct()
#2 /.../wp-content/plugins/elementor-pro/plugin.php(108): ElementorPro\Plugin->__construct()
#3 /.../wp-content/plugins/elementor-pro/plugin.php(339): ElementorPro\Plugin::instance()
#4 /.../wp-content/plugins/elementor-pro/elementor-pro.php(57): require('/home/glassbloc...')
#5 /.../wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(287): elementor_pro_load_plugin('')
#6 /.../wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(311): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array)
#7 /hom in /home/.../wp-content/plugins/elementor-pro/core/app/modules/site-editor/module.php on line 80
```

I am not sure how to fix this and I have searched for similar issues, but everyone's issue is completely different.  The website is [www.glassblockwarehouse.com](http://www.glassblockwarehouse.com) if you wish to see it.

I am not an advanced programmer, so please be specific if you don't mind. Thank you as always for all your assistance.

Comment: As this seems a bug related to Elementor Pro, you should report it in their support threads, as StackOverFlow doesn't handle any software support.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably downgrade the Elementor Pro plugin if the error pops up after updating your plugins.

Comment: COuld you elaborate o nwhy do you think that could help?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).